# Increase spacing in table of figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I use this code to set the space in my table of contents:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{8pt}
```

I was hoping I could use the same code to set the space in my table of figures, but it doesn't work for table of figures. How can I modify this code to also work for table of figures?

Comment: `\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{8pt}` perhaps? This depends on the position of usage and the document class (and other packages) however. Sometimes the command must be written directly to the LoT itself. Please provide a compilable document in order to get more help!

Comment: Thanks, I just used \doublespacing and \singlespacing and it looks alright.

Comment: Hm, that's not the preferred way to increase spacings, however.

Comment: I meant `\cftbeforefigskip`, actually -- I confused it with the `LoT`...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer this is the answer. Please make it one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tocloft` package provides `\cftbeforeXskip` length registers for X begin `part`, `chapter` etc, but also for `fig` and `tab`.

Changing it for all values can be done with `\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{10pt}` etc., a mid-document change must be written explicitly to the `LoF`, however, with `\addtocontents{lof}{...}` (see the code below).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\clearpage

\section{Foo}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Yet Another figure}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{Foobar}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setlength{\protect\cftbeforefigskip}{10pt}}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Yet Another figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \caption{More figure content}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

[image]